# WmiPrvSE memory leak on Windows 2008 *R2*

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wmi, memory-leak

I've seen references on Windows 2008 to WmiPrvSE leaks, but nothing about Windows 2008 R2.

We're running R2 on top of Hyper-V (2008). We are also running NSClient++ for monitoring from opsview. Over time, WmiPrvSE.exe starts to use a lot of memory, causing memory alert issues (less than 10% free). VM has 2GB, WmiPrvSE consumes up to 500-600MB before I kill it.

Killing the process doesn't seem to have any negative effect; it starts up again and I haven't noticed any problems. But after a day or two, it's back in the same situation.

Any ideas on what to do? Resource Monitor doesn't show any Disk or Network IO by WmiPrvSE.exe. Just slowly climbing private memory...

Edited to add: We aren't running clustering, or Windows System Resource Manager. The only regular WMI user I can guess is NSClient++, but we don't seem to have this problem on other servers.

Answer (score 3):

See: [MS KB article 981314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732338/wmiprvse-process-leaks-memory-on-2008-server-r2)

Comment: This 981314 hotfix appears to have fixed a problem we were having on a Sharepoint development server with wmiprvse.exe consuming 400-500 MBs of RAM on a Windows 2008 R2 64-bit server.

Answer (score 0):

We are using 2k8 r2 & nsclient++ and also seeing 500-600 mb memory usage after a few days. 
As you mentioned, a restart of the wmi service solves the issue for a few days.
My current suspicion is nsclient++ is not cleaning up it's wmi resources properly.
Our problem got worse when we increased our monitoring frequency.

Gareth